# How to release the player of the Exoplayer PlayerView?

Tags: android, exoplayer

I use two different instances of PlayerView (com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView) in two fragments in my app. Both of these Playerview instances use the same SimpleExoPlayer instance for the player. In fragment1 the playerView1 works fine and also when I go to the fragment2 the playerView2 which uses the same SimpleExoPlayer instace works fine. The problem is when I go back to the fragment1 the playerView1 doesn't show anything. I think before going back to the 1st fragment I should release the player of the playerView2 but I don't know how.

In fragment1 (kotlin):

```
playerView1.player = myGlobalSimpleExoPlayer
```

In fragment2 (kotlin):

```
playerView2.player = myGlobalSimpleExoPlayer
```

Comment: Are you getting black screen?

Comment: Yes, When I return to the 1st fragment the view shows black screen

Comment: Have you tried playerView.setKeepContentOnPlayerReset(true);. This is general problem of Exoplayer.

Comment: No, Should I use this in 1st fragment or 2nd or both?

Comment: I doesn't work. I added this to both views.

Comment: Are you using same video for both screens? If yes then you can use shared-element concept. In my case it was solved by setKeepContentOnPlayerReset. But I utilised shared-element concept as I was using same video

Comment: Yes I use the same video. Maybe I should use the same method.

Comment: Yes, that is very good option actually. This way there would be no-lag between fragment transition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying different methods finally I found the solution. I share the solution here maybe it would be useful for others with the same problem.

In each fragment before setting the player of the PlayerView I set null value for the player (You should do this each time you switch the fragments, not only the first time):

```
playerView.player = null // add this before setting the actual player
playerView.player = myGlobalSimpleExoPlayer
```

Comment: God bless you, this has plagued me for 4 days now. Thank you!!!!
PS. Can confirm this was the fix for Xamarin.android as well.

Comment: Even in 2023 with "androidx.media3.common.Player.Exoplayer" this seems to be working fine

Answer (score 3):

```
PlayerView.switchTargetView()
```

Is the correct way to do it

Comment: 2023: exoplayer api does not offer this call anymore ...